# Limpiar código android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo hacer que de mi código generado mediante android studio desaparezcan las referencias a archivos locales (`C:/xxx`). Por ejemplo, en workspace.xml (ello no impide su buen funcionamiento, simplemente se me ha pedido evitar esto por temas de higiene).

```
<entry key="$PROJECT_DIR$" value="C:\Users\ALUMNO\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-3.3-all\55gk2rcmfc6p2dg9u9ohc3hw9\gradle-3.3" />
```

Además, también me gustaría saber, en caso de cambiar los nombres de las carpetas de java que comienzan por "`com.xxx.xxx`", además de cambiar el package si debería cambiar algo más.

Comment: Disculpa, pero no entiendo exactamente qué es lo que quieres decir. Deseas cambiar los nombres de los paquetes para que sean más cortos?

Comment: sí. Básicamente me gustaría acortar dichos nombres y modificarlos, además de que no aparezcan referencias a C. El problema es que le llame inicialmente al proyecto "prueba" y ahora querría cambiarle el nombre, pero me encuentro con que hay diversas referencias al mismo.

Comment: Me gustaria saber que referencias a C (drive c) tienes en tu aplicación, puedes agregar informaciôn. Sinceramente sería la primera ocasión que veo esto en una aplicación, obviamente no funcionaría en un dispositivo real o producción.

Comment: Yo uso refactor desde dentro de androis studio shiflt+f6 y así cambio lo que deseo

Answer (score 2):

> Me gustaría saber cómo puedo hacer que de mi código generado mediante
>   android studio desaparezcan las referencias a archivos locales
>   (C:/xxx).

Puedes cambiar la lectura de archivos al folder /assets. En el caso de archivos .jar puedes crear el folder /libs y registrar los archivos en el archivo build.gradle.

> me gustaría saber, en caso de cambiar los nombres de las carpetas de
>   java que comienzan por "com.xxx.xxx

Puedes refactorizar el paquete o cambiarlo de nombre manualmente, pero recuerda que estos cambios de paquete, deben reflejarse en el `androidmanifest.xml` y en tu archivo `build.gradle`.

Si tienes vistas personalizadas, el acceso a estas desde los .xml es mediante el paquete por lo tanto también aqui debes realizar el cambio.

```
<com.mypaquete.myapp.vistas.vistapersonalizada>
```

Answer (score 2):

Aclaraciones preliminares:
No podes quitar las referencias y esperar que Android Studio funcione.
Sí se pueden descartar los archivos con referencias locales para guardar los fuentes, o pasárselos a otras personas. 
Esta respuesta asume que la necesidad pasa por ese lado.

Los proyectos de Android Studio pueden estar físicamente en cualquier carpeta. Las refencias locales no son importantes a tal punto que si guardas tus fuentes en sistema de control de versiones como Git o Subversion, esos archivos son ignorados.

Esto significa que podés move el proyecto a otra carpeta con el nombre que vos quieras. Borras los archivos con referencias locales (ver lista abajo), y estos se generan nuevamente cuando haces un build.

Esta es la lista de archivos que por default para Android Studio GIT ignora:

1) A nivel de Proyecto

1. *.iml
2. .gradle
3. /local.properties
4. /.idea/workspace.xml
5. /.idea/libraries
6. .DS_Store
7. /build
8. /captures
9. .externalNativeBuild

2) A nivel de módulo

1. /build

Para cambiar el nombre del package es como dice @Jorgesys.